# Monkey patch pandas: modify value_counts function at import

Tags: python, pandas, module, package, monkeypatching

I want to change the `value_counts` function in pandas, and I try to figure out why it is not working.

If I do

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.core.algorithms.value_counts = None

>>> pd.Series([1,2,3]).value_counts()

3    1
2    1
1    1
dtype: int64
```

I would expect to have a `TypeError`

However if I do

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.core.base.value_counts = None #or a modified function

>>> pd.Series([1,2,3]).value_counts()

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I get the `TypeError` .

What is the reason of this difference of behavior? 
How I can modify the `pd.core.algorithms.value_counts` function such that it changes the behavior of all classes that use it to construct `value_counts` methods?

Comment: Not sure how, but this might help: [Python monkey-patching like a boss](https://medium.com/@chipiga86/python-monkey-patching-like-a-boss-87d7ddb8098e)

Comment: added an explanation in my answer.  Hopefully, that makes it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try using `pd.core.base.IndexOpsMixin.value_counts = None` ?

This makes both `pd.Series.value_counts` and `pd.Index.value_counts` as `None`. Anything else you are looking at?

#### **Explanation:**

In `pd.core.base` there is an import `from pandas.core.algorithms import duplicated, unique1d, value_counts`

So, `pd.core.base.value_counts = pd.core.algorithms.value_counts`

Now, even if you make `pd.core.algorithms.value_counts` as `None`, the `value_counts` object in `base` still contains the old `value_counts` function. So, that doesn't work!

Obviously, if you make `pd.core.base.value_counts` directly `None` - that works out.

Which is the same as my solution really, as `pd.core.base.IndexOpsMixin.value_counts` just returns the `pd.core.base.value_counts`.